# Neural Networks Using Python and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am newbie to NN and I am trying to implement NN with Python/Numpy from the code I found at: 
"Create a Simple Neural Network in Python from Scratch"
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kft1AJ9WVDk)

My input array is:

```
array([[5.71, 5.77, 5.94],
   [5.77, 5.94, 5.51],
   [5.94, 5.51, 5.88],
   [5.51, 5.88, 5.73]])
```

Output array is:

```
array([[5.51],
   [5.88],
   [5.73],
   [6.41]])
```

after running the code, I see following results which are not correct:

```
synaptic_weights after training
[[1.90625275]
[2.54867698]
[1.07698312]]
outputs after training
[[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]]
```

Here is the core of the code:

```
for iteration in range(1000):
    input_layer = tr_input
    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, synapic_weights))

    error = tr_output - outputs

    adjustmnets = error * sigmoid_derivative(outputs)

    synapic_weights +=np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustmnets )

print('synaptic_weights after training')  
print(synapic_weights)

print('outputs after training')  
print(outputs)
```

What should I change in this code so it works for my data? Or shall I take different method? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Look into pandas and keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using a wrong activation function (i.e. sigmoid). The main reason why we use sigmoid function is because it exists between (**0 to 1)**. Therefore, it is especially used for models where we have to predict the probability as an output.Since probability of anything exists only between the range of 0 and 1, **sigmoid** is the right choice.

If you want to train a model to predict the values in your array, you should use a regression model. Otherwise, you can convert your output into labels (for example are 5.x to 0 and 6.x to 1) and retrain your model.

Comment: @arminrd  Thanks for your valuable time and response. You are right. I was not paying attention to it. I will try different regression models, but if you think about a specific model, please comment it. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps involved in my neural network implementation.

- Randomly initialize weights (θ Theta)
- Implement forward propagation
- Compute cost function
- Implement back propagation to compute partial derivative
- Use gradient descent

```
def forward_prop(X, theta_list):

    m = X.shape[0]
    a_list = []
    z_list = []
    
    a_list.append(np.insert(X, 0, values=np.ones(m), axis=1))
   
    idx = 0
    for idx, thera in enumerate(theta_list):
        z_list.append(a_list[idx] * (theta_list[idx].T))
        if idx != (len(theta_list)-1):
            a_list.append(np.insert(sigmoid(z_list[idx]), 0, values=np.ones(m), axis=1))
        else:
            a_list.append(sigmoid(z_list[idx]))

    return a_list, z_list
```

```
def back_prop(params, input_size, hidden_layers, num_labels, X, y, regularization, regularize):

    m = X.shape[0]
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    
    theta_list = []
    startCount = 0
    idx = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(hidden_layers):
        if idx == 0:
            startCount = val * (input_size + 1)
            theta_list.append(np.matrix(np.reshape(params[:startCount], (val, (input_size + 1)))))
        if idx != 0:
            tempCount = startCount
            startCount += (val * (hidden_layers[idx-1] + 1))
            theta_list.append(np.matrix(np.reshape(params[tempCount:startCount], (val, (hidden_layers[idx-1] + 1)))))
        if idx == (len(hidden_layers)-1):
            theta_list.append(np.matrix(np.reshape(params[startCount:], (num_labels, (val + 1)))))


    a_list, z_list= forward_prop(X, theta_list)
    J = cost(X, y, a_list[len(a_list)-1], theta_list, regularization, regularize)
    
    d_list = []
    d_list.append(a_list[len(a_list)-1] - y)
    
    idx = 0
    while idx < (len(theta_list)-1):
        d_temp = np.multiply(d_list[idx] * theta_list[len(a_list) - 2 - idx], sigmoid_gradient(a_list[len(a_list) - 2 - idx]))
        d_list.append(d_temp[:,1:])
        idx += 1    
    
    delta_list = []
    for theta in theta_list:
        delta_list.append(np.zeros(theta.shape))

    for idx, delta in enumerate(delta_list):
        delta_list[idx] = delta_list[idx] + ((d_list[len(d_list) - 1 -idx].T) * a_list[idx])
        delta_list[idx] = delta_list[idx] / m
   
    if regularize:
        for idx, delta in enumerate(delta_list):
            delta_list[idx][:, 1:] = delta_list[idx][:, 1:] + (theta_list[idx][:, 1:] * regularization)

    grad_list = np.ravel(delta_list[0])
    idx = 1
    while idx < (len(delta_list)):
        grad_list = np.concatenate((grad_list, np.ravel(delta_list[idx])), axis=None)
        idx += 1

    return J, grad_list
```

```
def cost(X, y, h, theta_list, regularization, regularize):

    m = X.shape[0]
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)

    J = (np.multiply(-y, np.log(h)) - np.multiply((1 - y), np.log(1 - h))).sum() / m
        
    if regularize:
        regularization_value = 0.0
        for theta in theta_list:
            regularization_value += np.sum(np.power(theta[:, 1:], 2))
        J += (float(regularization) / (2 * m)) * regularization_value
        

    return J
```

[Implementation](https://github.com/AmaldevTA/ML_Basics/blob/master/003_Neural_Networks/Neural_network.ipynb)